# How to find substring (or possible substring) from a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, string, search

I am working with NodeJS and developing a resume parser to extract the possible technical skills and roles from the resume

for example, If a resume has `nodejs` then it will count it as technical skills and similarly finds all the roles or positions held by the candidate.

Right now I am comparing a predefined array of strings with the text from the resume to get all the tags.
But I want to get all the tags even if there is a spelling mistake in the resume or a similar matching role or skills.

for example, if the predefined string is `team lead` and the resume has `team leader`
then It should count as a role.
Similar if the predefined string is `nodejs` and the resume has `node.js`. It should be counted as a skill.

any solution?

Comment: You're looking for a "fuzzy search" js library.

Comment: So you are looking for "approximate string matching"?

Comment: [fuse.js](https://fusejs.io/) is an easy one

Comment: Can u show me the implementation I am not able to implement

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to catch *similar* strings with things like [Soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) or a [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

However, you'll probably just want to manually maintain a dictionary of possible similar words and check against any of those.

```js
var tagsAndAlternates = {
  "nodejs": ["nodejs", "node.js"],
  "team lead": ["team lead", "team leader"]
}
```

### Demo in Stacks Snippets

```js
var myTestString = `
I have done nodejs development as a team leader
`

var tagsAndAlternates = {
  "nodejs": ["nodejs", "node.js"],
  "team lead": ["team lead", "team leader"]
}

var tagEntries = Object.entries(tagsAndAlternates).map(([tag, spellings]) => {
    const foundMatch = spellings.some(word => myTestString.includes(word));
    return [tag, foundMatch]
})

console.log(Object.fromEntries(tagEntries))
```